# Show NSStatusItem menu only if App is active

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using this method to show the NSStatusItem menu only if application is Active.

```
-(void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu*)menu{  
    if(![NSApp isActive]){
        [menu cancelTracking];
    }
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]; 
}
```

It perfectly works, but cancelTracking seems to block the blue highlight of the NSStatusItem. So when i click on status menu item it doesn't show the submenu and it presents the main window, but the icon is not highlighted.
Is there a way to make it happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a custom view if you need more precise control over when the status item highlights itself. Then you can use `mouseDown:` etc. [This](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/03/04/using-maattachedwindow-with-an-nsstatusitem) is a good example of putting your custom view in a status item.